# In the context of APNs, does p8 and p12 mean token and certificate based authentication respectively?

Tags: authentication, apple-push-notifications

From what I know, PKCS 8 is often used to store private keys, and PKCS 12 is often used to store certificates.

And to communicate with APNs, you need authentication tokens or certificates.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html

Does that mean those .p8 files are keys used to create tokens, and those .p12 files are used as certificates?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Apple Push Notification Authentication Key (P8 format) is used to generate Server side tokens. You do not need a certificate here. (This is mainly used when you have multiple apps under the same account as this key is same for all the apps unlike certificates). So using a same connection, your provider can talk to multiple apps using a mandatory 'authorization' header. Every post request gets validated henceforth by APNS cloud using this header.

P12 format exist for generating Certificates for authenticating provider against a particular AppID. Here for every individual app, a separate certificate is required. You do not need 'authorization' header here as connection itself is authenticated.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. So now I can reuse the connection to send notifications to different apps. That makes sense. The only question is, why don't they design it like that in the first place.

Comment: True. But it's evolving. Previously there used to be certificate per topic, then came multi-topic certificate, then same multi-topic certificate for production & development, & now same key for account ID. :)

Answer (score 13):

### `.p8` is a key

The `.p8` is an **authentication token signing key**, or simply, **key**. Your server can use this to authenticate with APNs. You can use this to create a JWT token (A few objects encoded and signed) and send this to APNs to authenticate. Specifically you use the `.p8` to sign the JWT payload/ token, and append this signature to the JWT, and then encrypt it ([Signed, then Encrypted](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-11.2)). More information available in [Communicate with APNs using authentication tokens](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/deva05921840) and [Establishing a Token-Based Connection to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns). The way you would create the token is documented in 
[Communicating with APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1). For example, the JWT must be encrypted, and it must be less than 1 hour old. It provides access to all applications, so you must use the `apns-topic` request header to specify the application.

### `.p12` is a certificate

The `.p12` is a **certificate**. If your system has this certificate installed, it can use TLS and identify as you, so there's no further authentication needed. More information available in [Communicate with APNs using a TLS certificate](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev82a71386a). It provides access to one app.

**A good resource is 
[Communicating with APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1).**

---

> Does that mean those .p8 files are keys used to create tokens,

Yes

> and those .p12 files are used as certificates?

Yes